# Using regular expression, how can I match the first word after a particular string?

Tags: regex

For example, suppose my string is:

'governed by media laws'

I want to match 'media'

I've tried:

```
governed by ?([\w+]?)
```

but I only get'm'

How do I match the whole word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place the plus `+` outside the brackets `[ ]`, and there is no need for the question marks. Try this:

```
governed by ([\w]+)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/ZcaA0m/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<=governed by )\w+
```

https://regex101.com/r/ysl7V2/1